# Google Spreadsheet converting time automatically to current timezone

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with a cell with my current time.

For example: Meeting at: 17:15

Is there a way, when a person from another computer and timezone opens the spreadsheet, that he can see the time in his current time zone.

Example: Meeting at: 2:15 pm.

Something like cell: =convertTime(17:15,"UTC +1) that automatically shows the 17:15 UTC+1 in your time zone?

Thanks

Comment: Which timezone are you referring to here? A spreadsheet has a certain timezone, for all users that might open it. So which timezone should the function look for? Also, the spreadsheet content will always be the same, no matter which user opens it. I don't think what you want to do is possible. Could you please provide more details on your purpose?

Comment: I have a spreadsheet that people from different timezone can use. I created that sheet. So, now Im putting in a cell stuff like:
"I did this at 8pm"
If someone from a different timezone now opens the sheet, he see "Did that at 8pm", but thats wrong at his time zone. Is he, for example, 3h behind my time, I did that at 11pm his time. So I want that it shows 11pm, when he opens the document

Comment: I don't think that's possible. As I said before, the spreadsheet content is one, it doesn't matter which user opens it. Also, where would the timezone data come from?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show different cell values to different users.

---

Google Sheets has a timezone setting for each spreadsheet but it hasn't a built-in fuction able to get the timezone of the current user. By the other hand custom function are executed anonymously so they will not be able to automatically get the current user timezone.

One option is to use Google Apps Script to create an user interface like a dialog or sidebar that use client-side code to show date / time value in the active user timezone.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets